# CodeIgniter: Best way to implement External Objects (Objects that aren't models, views, or controllers)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

I want to add some classes to a CodeIgniter project that aren't models, views, or controllers. They will most likely be a built in Models/Controllers and used in various ways. Where should I store these classes, and what is the best way to implement them in CodeIgniter? (Or more generally, any MVC-based framework?).

EDIT: Looking through some of the codeIgniter documentation, it looks like adding the objects to a helper is the way to go, is that correct?

Comment: Don't put an object in a helper!!! Helpers are procedural, libraries are Objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CI is unlike a lot of MVC frameworks in that it doesn't make it challenging to integrate outside libraries. Generally, there are a couple approaches:

1. Just include()/require() the library and use it normally. This works fine most of the time, unless there's a naming conflict. CI mostly stays out of the way, so this isn't common. In this case, you can put the library wherever you feel like. Generally I try to keep them in a shared "libs" directory, outside of the document root, since I don't assume they'll only be used by CI.
2. Put your libraries in your applications/libraries and load them using the CI->load() method. This puts some restrictions on naming conventions, so you might need to massage existing libraries or write some sort of wrapper constructor. [The CI docs on creating libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) covers this pretty well.

Personally, I much prefer the first approach. It's one of the benefits of using CI.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if there is no possibility of it being a library, I will either put it in the helpers folder as objects_helper.php or, in special circumstances, in the same file as the Library object which calls it.

You might also look into a object factory library so you could use something like:

```
$this->factory->createUserObject( $name, $rank, $serial );
```

Finally, you could look into the hooks framework, but it does not sound like you *really* want to use that.

I would only use require/include if you feel that it does not make sense (from a code/philosophical perspective) in any other circumstance.  It is generally a good idea to work *within* a framework whenever possible.

Comment: never said it couldn't be a library, but you do bring up some good points/alternatives. The idea of a factory library seems like it could be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making it a library and just using $this->load->library(); To read mores see: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

There is a difference between libraries and helpers. If the outside library isn't object-oriented then you'll want it as a helper, if it is, then you should just be able to make it a library with no problem.